# How to search strings from 10Million+ amount of data rows

Tags: lucene, bigdata, amazon-redshift

In my database i have a table which has around 10 columns and 10 million+ rows. One column contains maximum of 1000 characters. Now i need to do searchers such as like '%cat%dog%'. I dont want to do any complex things. But when i run this in redshift it takes around 1second - 10 seconds to give me the results based on what i do. Is there any other option where i can store this data into (such as indexed files) so that i can get the results in less than 200ms.  I was looking into Lucine and i was not so convinced. Does any one know any services which provides the feature im looking into ?

Comment: Solr/Lucene is the way to go. Or, if you want to try something different, try http://crate.io/ - They wrap Lucene as the indexer.

Answer (score 0):

Google BigQuery might be an option for you. You can use `REGEXP_MATCH`  which allows you to use Regular expression for selecting records instead of `LIKE '%something%'`.

See [the query reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#regularexpressionfunctions) for details.